# image not positioned correctly after refreshing page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to center an image with keeping the correct aspect ratio of the image inside the div and centering it as well. I have the following html code:

```
<div class="product-large" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden;">
  <img src="/images/store_logos/c48edfde4dfb95efb42c5bb474fc249a2bc84253.jpeg" alt="" class="js-fix" style="margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px;">
  <img src="/images/store_logos/c48edfde4dfb95efb42c5bb474fc249a2bc84253.jpeg" class="zoomImg" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: -3.3157894736842106px; opacity: 0; width: 500px; height: 760px; border: none; max-width: none;">
</div>
```

With the following javascript code to center the image:

```
$(".product-large img").each(function () {
        //get height and width (unitless) and divide by 2
        var hWide = ($(this).width()) / 2; //half the image's width
        var hTall = ($(this).height()) / 2; //half the image's height, etc.

        // attach negative and pixel for CSS rule
        hWide = '-' + hWide + 'px';
        hTall = '-' + hTall + 'px';

        $(this).addClass("js-fix").css({
            "margin-left": hWide,
                "margin-top": hTall
        });
    });
#main.product-detail .product-banner .product-large img
{
    max-width:437px;
    max-height:437px;
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
}

#main.product-detail .product-banner .product-large {
    background-color: #F3EFEA;
    height: 437px;
    width: 437px;
}
```

It works perfectly fine on first load, however the second time the image position or broken (i.e: it's not centered correctly).

For a working example, you can check the link [below](http://dev.shopious.com/items/183/Bow-Detail-Chiffon-Blouse) and then refresh the page couple times. You'll notice that the image is not centered the 2nd/3rd time. Any idea why?

Comment: Actually, I noticed that when I opened the page for the first time, the margins for `.js-fix` weren't there. But can I ask why you are using `javascript` to center the image? Why not using `text-align: center` on `.product-large` and drop the `position:absolute` form the img?

Comment: What for is `js-fix` class? I think it's not being used.

Comment: @LRA I am trying to center the image but I don't want to break the aspect ratio, so I thought that would solve it

Comment: I'm not sure what is happening here, but I think it has something to do with the the image being in the cache the second time. Can't you just use CSS to align using the display:table-cell technique?

Comment: @koenp how do you do that?

Comment: I'll answer it as a real answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't get this working I suggest you just use a 100% CSS aligning using the table-cell approach. Lesser JavaScript is always better :) Here's a jsfiddle of how to do that

http://jsfiddle.net/fMJDj/1

And the code in the fiddle:

```
<div>
  <img src="http://explodingdog.com/drawing/awesome.jpg" />
</div>

div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  height: 800px;
  width: 800px;
}
img {
  max-width:437px;
  max-height:437px;
}
```